# How to defer react app render until remote data is loaded to local/session storage?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, session-storage

I have a react application that needs read configuration JSON from remote API before rendering. I intend to store the configuration data in local or session storage for access after the app is mounted.
I tried to fetch the remote data in the html header using javascript and store it in session storage, but the react component doesn't get the data every time, it seems the app is rendered before the configuration data is stored in session storage.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Suggest adding your code so we can assist you in fixing it perhaps

Answer (score 0):

If sounds like you need to wrap your application in a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) which will take care of checking for previously downloaded config in session storage, or download it if it's not there. This component should show a loading state until you have what you need, to use the application.